# Parse RSS modification

Tags: xml, parsing, rss

Sorry to ask but need some help. I'm using the below script shown to parse an RSS feed of blog entries. In this example, I'm using ["Mashable" feed](http://feeds.mashable.com/Mashable?format=xml) as the feed source to demonstrate.

**Issue**:

The blog entry images and links appear correctly. But the problem is, I'd like to also include the blog entry **titles** for output as well, and not sure how to write it.

Can anyone take a look and offer a suggestion as to how I might include the entry title (+ link) in the below script if possible?

I'd be grateful for any suggestions or help. Thank you.

**Script**:

```
$parseRSS({
url: "http://feeds.mashable.com/Mashable?format=xml",
count: 16,
callback: function(posts) {
    for(var i = 0; i < posts.length; i++) {
        var img = posts[i].content.split('src="')[1].split('"')[0];
        var link = posts[i].link;
        document.body.innerHTML += '<a href="' + link + '"><img src="' + img + '"></a>';
    }
} });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`posts` array contains also titles, so you just need to append them to the document body:

```
var title = posts[i].title;
var link = posts[i].link;
document.body.innerHTML += '<h1>' + title + '</h1>';
document.body.innerHTML += '<p><a href="' + link + '">link</a></p>';
document.body.innerHTML += '<a href="' + link + '"><img src="' + img + '"></a><br>';
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/janih/pen/aOwvbZ)

Comment: Hi Janih -- didn't see this earlier -- thanks MUCH. Works! The other issue I'm having is trying to display this http://codepen.io/janih/pen/aOwvbZ also more in grid format (rather than one long scroll) --- is easy to do with just images but haven't been able to array this as a grid with the h1, p as they're generated in RSS ...would welcome any thoughts there...  and again, thanks much for your fix above... Upvoted and selected.

Comment: You could make [a table](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_table.asp) and add posts to table cells in the for loop or use css styles(maybe [Bootstrap layout](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid) or your custom css).